# shape voice linux traffic using tc

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping, traffic-management, traffic-filtering

How to set up a traffic control policy so voice traffic has maximum bandwidth of an specific interface?
I tried

```
tc qdisc add dev $WIFI handle 1: root tbf rate 10mbit burst 32kbit latency 10ms
```

but how to determine that this bandwidth will adjusted especially for voice traffic